# golang: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

I am new to golang and currently following this tutorial and source code here - http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/part2.go

After building this file, I am getting

```
calvin$ ./mywebwiki2 
2012/07/23 17:12:59 http: panic serving [::1]:58820: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:576 (0x3f202)
    _func_003: buf.Write(debug.Stack())
/private/tmp/bindist454984655/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1443 (0x10c79)
/private/tmp/bindist454984655/go/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.c:128 (0x11745)
/private/tmp/bindist454984655/go/src/pkg/runtime/thread_darwin.c:418 (0x148b5)
/Users/calvin/work/gowiki/mywebwiki2.go:33 (0x2248)
    viewHandler: fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>%s</h1><div>%s</div>", p.Title, p.Body)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:690 (0x331ae)
    HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP: f(w, r)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:926 (0x34030)
    (*ServeMux).ServeHTTP: mux.handler(r).ServeHTTP(w, r)
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:656 (0x32fc1)
    (*conn).serve: handler.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/private/tmp/bindist454984655/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:271 (0xed7f)
2012/07/23 17:12:59 http: panic serving [::1]:58821: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Any idea what I did wrong to be causing this apparent memory corruption?

Comment: This error may also occur if the file requested isn't there (with no error handling). For me I forgot to create the test.txt file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's an ignored err at line 36. The error probably says `open .txt: no such file or directory` if you tested in browser using URL `http://localhost:8080/view/` or `open foo.txt: no such file or directory` if you tested in browser using URL `http://localhost:8080/view/foo`. In the later case there must be a file "foo.txt" in your working directory for this example code to work. After that the code seems to work for me locally.

Someone should probably fill an issue about the ignored error value.

Comment: yup. realized my silly mistake after chatting with some one on go-nuts irc channel. thanks!

Comment: There is an ignored error on the next line too from `fmt.Fprintf`

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, you created the file TestPage previously.  Which is the page you should be navigating to when you first build the server.  In the tutorial, they have you navigate to `view/test` instead of `view/TestPage` as you should which is what creates the confusion.